# IntelliJ environment variable pointing to IDE config directory

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ there are pre-defined env variables one can use like:

`$MODULE_DIR$` - current module directory

`$PROJECT_DIR$` - project root directory (where .idea folder sits)

`$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$` - installation directory

Is there a variable I can use that points to the configuration folder of IntelliJ - e.g:

`C:\Users\<username>\.IdeaIC<version>\config`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this, the variable is called: `APPLICATION_CONFIG_DIR`

It looks like there is not a document or web page where JetBrains would list all the IDE environmental variables used / declared or available. After a purely random and lucky search I found scratch files are saved under `APPLICATION_CONFIG_DIR`.